# Adding glass effect to listbox item

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem, aero-glass

I have a stackpanel with a background image. Inside the stackpanel there is a ListBox and its background is set to transparent, what I need is to blur (glass effect) the background image only the part that comes under the listbox item. I tried to add a rectangle to transparent color in the listbox item template and then added a blurred effect but it doesn't work. This is what I am trying to achieve. [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across [this](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/403/Glass-Behavior-for-WPF.aspx) some time ago, maybe will help with what you're after.

[image]